Nginx Rewrites: Hide .php extension, unless when explicit requested
I know there are probably thousands of questions about nginx + PHP-FPM, but I could not find an answer that closely matches my scenario. The sheer number makes it hard to tell useful answers from noise...
I want to hide the PHP file from my URLs, unless it's given out explicitly:
My application's root is as follows:
/app
|
└--- application
|    └ (PHP code for the application)
└--- www
|    |  index.php (application entry point - Executes code from the application folder)
|    |  alternate.php
|    |
|    └--- images/
|    |        logo.png 
|    |        ...
|    └--- scripts/
|    |       selectbox.js
|    |       ...
|    └-- library_1/
|    |       script1.js
|    |       script2.js
|    |       script3.js
|    |       ...
|    └---- subdir_1/
|    |     |       script4.js
|    |     |       ...

I'm currently using this nginx configuration that allows me to serve everything correctly:
server {
    server_name localhost default;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /app/www/;

    location ~* \.php$ {
        client_max_body_size 16M;
        try_files      $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   app:9000;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME      $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
    }
}

I want to hide the .php files from my URLs. They currently look like this:
https://my-app.com/index.php?query_1=value1&param2=value2

The desired outcome could be:

If no PHP file is specified, hide it from the URL:
https://my-app.com/?query_1=value1&param2=value2 would execute /app/www/index.php
If a specific PHP file is indicated, execute it:
https://my-app.com/alternate.php?query_1=value1&param2=value2 would execute /app/www/alternate.php
If a non-existent file is requested, return 404: https://my-app.com/foo.php?query_1=value1 yields an HTTP Not Found

https://my-app.com/alternate.php?query_1=value1&param2=value2

Which would then trigger the execution of alternate.php instead of the traditional entry point.

[sf] would be a better place to ask questions about nginx configuration.

I would think the common CMS router examples such as WordPress would work. Basically “try the literal path”, “try the path as a folder with an index file” (optional, skip if you aren’t using folders), “fallback to router file”. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/

Your configuration seems to meet your requirements listed as bullet points. What is it not doing correctly. Show an example.

@RichardSmith If I specifically request the index.php file, it does not hide it.
